# How to structure recurring tasks for an user on Firestore?

Tags: firebase, database-design, architecture, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building a todo application to teach myself how to build mobile apps and work with data models. The app is very date oriented, with each day being a "page". I'm saving the tasks under each day's bucket on Firestore, which is working fine, although I'm not sure that's a good practice.

My problem is now with recurring tasks. I'd like to flag a task to repeat daily, weekly or monthly, but duplicating the same task on every single "day/week/month" sounds crazy.

I've thought about creating a bucket with all the recurring tasks, and perhaps referencing that task in the days it's relevant, with the status of checked or not sitting in the day's document.

My current structure is:

```
User
└───Inbox   
└───Days
    └───Year(2019)
        └───Month(Nov)
            └───Day(19)
                └───Todos
                │   └───todoId
                │       └───complete?(bol)
                │       └───created_at
                │       └───title
                └───Notes
```

1. What would be a good structure/design to have recurring tasks given that model and Firestore structure?
2. Is that model any good? If not, what would be a better approach?

Comment: Hey Mattheus - if you think the answer is good can you mark it as best answer (check mark below the upvote count) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bravo on just learning.

I'm not sure what recurring tasks you're referring to, but based on what I could glean from the rest of your post, I don't think your model is something you'll appreciate counting on when you want to add more features later on.

I would instead use a structure that is much simpler and allows for easy querying. Something like this:

```
Todos
--> Todo1
-----> Date: Timestamp
-----> Complete: true
-----> UID: 12345
---> Todo2
-----> Date: Timestamp
-----> Complete: false
-----> UID: 67890
```

Querying on a simple structure like this would be as simple as:

"All todos by 67890"

Or

"All todos by 67890 for Today"

Or

"All incomplete todos for user 12345 where date > yesterday"

For dates you can simply store the times such that you can look for any results in a range, and to do a day you just do midnight to midnight. E.g. All posts from 12:00 Mon. to 12:00 Tues.

Comment: By recurring tasks/todos I mean tasks that will repeat. Like "take medicine" to repeat every day. Thanks for suggesting a different structure. Is that Todos bucket inside each User's bucket? Or is it a general Todos for EVERY todo in the product?

Comment: I would just do a single/general bucket for all todos. As for daily repeat items, you can't do an OR statement, so you can't query for "date == today" or "repeating" but you can just make two calls, one for today's dates and one for all repeating tasks and then collate them, I think that would work super easily.

Comment: Right, so the repeating todos would also leave on a general bucket with all the repeating todos, from all users. The todo would need to have a reference to the userID then, right? Appreciate your response!

Comment: Yeah I would treat them as the same except when there are specific characteristics that require them to be treated differently. E.g. one thing you'll want to figure out is how to store "Complete" for any given day, perhaps this is just changing Complete from boolean to a map where each key in the map is a day and each day's value is boolean. Instead of worrying about any day "incomplete" being in the map, you can just safely assume that any day not present in the map is an incomplete day for that todo!

Comment: Sorry, another question. Doesn't that mean I'll need to scan EVERY single todo just to show todos related to one person? I know I can filter and have Firestore rules to ensure people only see what they're supposed to but, scan through everything to determine wha's related to a single user seems expensive. Am I getting something wrong? Thanks again!

Comment: No problem! Can you ask this in another question so it could help someone in the future? Happy to answer, nudge here and we can delete after.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know if this question is still relevant, but from me trying to do a very similar thing. I believe you set up good cloud functions and good cloud scheduler to create recurring events. I have a specific collection for recurring events (my app does weekly)and every Sunday with cloud scheduler I run a Google cloud function that creates the events for the next week. I figure you can adjust for your use case.
Here is the link https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/schedule-export